# How to trigger a <div> on a webpage by click of a button on the webpage using django?

Tags: html, django

I am making a webpage where there are multiple buttons and whenever a button is clicked, an area displays the associated thing with the button. How can I trigger the button using GET and POST request and block so that on click of the button, that  element is displayed there?

I tried using GET and POST request but I am getting some errors. I can use some help if somebody provide insight on it.

Comment: You are looking for AJAX.

Comment: My backend code is in python. Does using Ajax will be fine with that?

Comment: That's up to you. If you want to load an entire page again, the simple way to do this is to make the button perform a GET with a query parameter, for example: `index?page=downloads` and then in the Python code to parse it and show the proper page. This is known as routing. Have you looked at the routing page in Django?

Comment: Yeah I tried that. But I wanted it to work like without getting reloaded. Is mixing Ajax and django will be fine? Or for button triggering, I have to use GET?

Comment: Then yes, you need AJAX. And yes, mixing them is fine. Or you could use iFrames; but you probably don't want to do that.